# Event Discount Based on Number of Participants Selecting Price Set Option

Tags: civievent, civicontribute, cividiscount

I'm working on a child care event for a conference. The way the pricing is set up, you have different sessions for child care with a discount applied for two or more children in the same session. So:

- Saturday all day ($30 1 child; $40 2 or more children)
- Saturday morning ($15 1 child; $25 2 or more)
- Saturday afternoon ($15 1 child; $25 2 or more)

I am assuming in order to do this the way it's structured I have to use hooks to modify pricing? I'm assuming civicrm_buildAmount is the appropriate hook. Any suggestions on how to approach what I'm trying to do. I'm not entirely sure how I would review all price sets for registrants to say (pseudo code):

if ( more than one registrant selects $option['saturday all day']) {
   $option['amount'] = 40/total registrants selecting this option
}

Any thoughts are appreciated.

Thanks,
Rachel

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge you have started in the right path and that would be the best way to process priceset - yes BuildAmount hook is used for handling the priceset amount

Also I guess you should have already known about discount module if not please refer to the link below - If this works in anyway

refer -  https://civicrm.org/extensions/cividiscount

All the best - I guess this helps !!!

Comment: Thanks Ramesh. I saw Cividiscount, but skimming the info I didn't see a way to do what I was looking for. At least not without having participants manually enter a code. Fantastic extension though.

Comment: Yes for more function hook would be better